# React Native version mismatch. JS V: 0.49.3 RN V: 0.59.9

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

Since I updated React Native version I'm facing with this issue.

[image]

All I find about this error make reference to having more than 1 Node terminal opened but this is not happening to me.

I have tried all they say about close the terminals, reset the cache, etc and nothing changes.

This happens only with react-native run-android, in iOS it doesn't happen.

Also, I can build the APK with no problems, but I cannot run in debug mode to debug the app via react-native run-android.

What could I do?

Comment: How did you update react-native? It looks like the JavaScript which is bundled in the Android project was previously built with the older react-native dependency. If you're running in debug generally the app will load the JavaScript from Metro, this is defined in the build.gradle unless you've changed this then you might have to perform a `react-native bundle`. If you're launching the app in debug try launching Metro with `react-native start --reset-cache` and reloading your app.

Comment: I have tried ti run react-native start --reset-cache a lot of time and nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix to this problem.

I have to clarify that it only was happening on Android 9.

I had to add in the Android Manifest this line of code:

```
<application
  ...
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  ...
```

For more information about this issue check this [link](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

Answer (score 0):

you should restart js.This problem because your react-native update.
run npm start.
or try uninstall app and run react-native run-android.

Comment: try npm install or yarn install?